# Perfectly aligning one div with another

Tags: css

I'm attempting to position a circular pie-shaped progress bar div behind the circular transparency of another div. Since the div I'm aligning with is relative with an absolute positioned child image div, I put the "pie" div as a child element of that relative positioned div, also positioned absolutely, and set padding properties as percentages thinking that would ensure it sized responsively with the sibling/parent divs.

[image]

It looks good at first, but if I resize the window it doesn't stay. How can I ensure it stays properly aligned and responsive if not by setting the padding?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/RwVJZEe

Edit: Sorry I guess I should have mentioned this, but this is an animated progress bar, not a static image. So combining them into one png is not an answer, I need to dynamically position the circular div behind the transparency of the logo png so it can function as a progress bar.

```js
const pieCharts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-percentage]');

if (pieCharts) {
  for (let i = 0; i < pieCharts.length; i += 1) {
    const slice = pieCharts[i];
    const percentage = slice.getAttribute('data-percentage');
    const circumference = 31.4;
    const strokeDash = Math.round((percentage * circumference) / 100);
    const strokeDashArray = `${strokeDash} ${circumference}`;

    slice.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', strokeDashArray);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #26004b;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: open_sans;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  height: 13.714%;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

.pie {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 14%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo,
.logo-animation {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo img,
.logo-animation img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo-animation {
  display: none;
}

.title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: clamp(2vw, 8vw, 10vh);
  display: flex;
  top: 0%;
}

.menu-button {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  height: 86.286%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 0% 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 61.8%;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15vw;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4em solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -2em;
  margin-bottom: -2em;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen" class="screen">
  <div id="menu_bar" class="menu-bar">
    <div id="logo" class="logo" data-flip-id="logo"> <img id="logo_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/D9LOkQI.png">
      <div id="pie" class="pie">
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 20" data-percentage="50">
          <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="white" />
          <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent" stroke="tomato" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="title" class="title">Title</div>
    <div id="menu_button" class="menu-button"> <img id="menu_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/l6GysYf.png"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="display" class="display">
    <div id="speech_bubble" class="speech-bubble">
      <div id="logo_animation" class="logo-animation" data-flip-id="logo">
        <img id="logo_animation_image" src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/Z1oYdpUd9Txyop1jdH/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611436e68e9fdddc32ce5e4e6c3a4730caba6ef8f0c&rid=giphy.gif&ct=s">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just create one picture with those two file in some graphic program?

Comment: @ЖнецЪ It's not a picture, it's an SVG path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a perfectly responsive design based mostly on yours and solving your alignment issue.

```js
  const pieCharts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-percentage]');

    if (pieCharts) {
    for (let i = 0; i < pieCharts.length; i += 1) {
    const slice = pieCharts[i];
    const percentage = slice.getAttribute('data-percentage');
    const circumference = 31.4;
    const strokeDash = Math.round((percentage * circumference) / 100);
    const strokeDashArray = `${strokeDash} ${circumference}`;

    slice.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', strokeDashArray);
    }
    }
```

```css
* {
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html, body {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #26004b;
    font-size: 2vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: open_sans;
    }

    .screen {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    }

    .menu-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    /* changed */
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0%;
    background: #504;
    }

    .logo {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    left: 30px;
    top: 48%;
    }

    .pie {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    left: 30px;
    top: -13.5px;
    }

    .logo-animation img {
    position: fixed;
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 20%;
    }

    .logo-animation {
    display: none;
    }

    .title {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    position: relative;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: hack;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    top: -15px;
    }

    .menu-button {
    grid-column: 3/4;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%
    top: -20px;
    }

    .menu-button img {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
    right: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    }

    .display {
    position: relative;
    height: 85%;
    width: 100vw;
    }

    .speech-bubble {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 80% 0% 20%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 70%;
    width: 90vw;
    margin: auto;
    top:20px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    }

    .speech-bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15vw;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 4em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -2em;
    margin-bottom: -2em;
    z-index: 5;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title></title>
  </head>

    <body>
    <div id="screen" class="screen">
    <div id="menu_bar" class="menu-bar">
    <div id="logo" class="logo" data-flip-id="logo">
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" viewBox="0 0 20 24" width="20" height="24">
    <path style="fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.3;" d="M 7.4347575,23.687249 C 6.7657083,23.617747 5.8743833,23.456411 5.3343024,23.30705 4.2494383,23.00703 3.0321409,22.586564 2.5787262,22.355249 l -0.161491,-0.08239 0.2083834,-0.371601 C 3.31636,20.669493 3.7214077,19.3757 3.8787139,17.898658 3.9446758,17.2793 3.9447325,17.198031 3.8795414,16.712217 3.6584171,15.064358 3.2545292,14.221128 1.7924095,12.354738 1.1731552,11.564262 0.93553847,11.203828 0.69435576,10.689133 -0.21376451,8.7511602 0.36640093,5.0448055 1.8831808,3.0943901 3.7676419,0.67117597 7.6712465,-0.36965586 11.223573,0.60392863 c 0.639085,0.17515361 1.528585,0.52414417 1.8125,0.71112447 0.113841,0.074974 0.377197,0.2381938 0.585234,0.3627113 0.718899,0.4302856 1.128517,0.7363067 1.559014,1.164722 0.777085,0.7733277 1.162783,1.3220852 1.444944,2.0558187 0.287294,0.7470796 0.383709,1.3364182 0.447684,2.7364822 0.06268,1.3717627 0.173529,1.691786 0.864735,2.4965687 1.039786,1.210641 1.207568,1.459947 1.209247,1.796815 8.1e-4,0.162085 -0.02039,0.206692 -0.161107,0.338983 -0.08952,0.08416 -0.28389,0.19807 -0.434322,0.254529 -0.349284,0.13109 -0.452424,0.199434 -0.531375,0.352109 -0.07952,0.153766 -0.05531,0.2826 0.139422,0.742055 0.133326,0.314572 0.143059,0.363489 0.09893,0.4972 -0.05975,0.181042 -0.332904,0.422913 -0.564976,0.50027 -0.09444,0.03148 -0.177879,0.07577 -0.185428,0.09841 -0.0075,0.02265 0.1043,0.07866 0.248554,0.12447 0.334691,0.106285 0.383795,0.179954 0.260595,0.390962 -0.336461,0.576266 -0.321379,0.519649 -0.358266,1.344871 -0.04993,1.116967 -0.05865,1.168717 -0.230744,1.369776 -0.338544,0.395513 -0.847355,0.50361 -2.043859,0.43422 -0.435368,-0.02525 -0.972723,-0.05643 -1.194121,-0.06929 -0.712512,-0.04138 -1.161767,0.110795 -1.566106,0.530483 -0.277495,0.288029 -0.499456,0.682957 -0.643985,1.145823 -0.08825,0.282641 -0.09919,0.399826 -0.09888,1.059322 4.24e-4,0.869212 0.06746,1.178721 0.384783,1.77626 0.104203,0.196223 0.174583,0.370927 0.156399,0.388231 -0.05426,0.05163 -0.723296,0.242688 -1.172458,0.334817 -1.037513,0.212809 -2.5956568,0.272259 -3.8152335,0.145568 z m 7.8076415,-7.541143 c 0.487942,-0.244106 0.991808,-0.806307 0.872425,-0.973427 -0.02145,-0.03002 -0.353615,-0.441097 -0.738149,-0.913497 -0.384534,-0.4724 -1.351642,-1.661153 -2.149131,-2.641673 -1.832725,-2.2533543 -1.677869,-2.0749272 -1.802913,-2.0773387 -0.08,-0.00154 -0.173813,-0.086634 -0.387983,-0.3519101 L 10.754176,8.8383847 10.947432,8.5675619 C 11.176381,8.2467174 11.48233,7.6064246 11.576996,7.25 11.682255,6.8536958 11.740546,6.264033 11.708943,5.9152542 11.553337,4.197947 10.445213,2.8388591 8.7843482,2.328307 8.4352749,2.2210013 8.3511914,2.2121056 7.6859973,2.2121056 c -0.6643614,0 -0.7499741,0.00903 -1.1016949,0.116193 C 5.7546575,2.5810778 5.0451715,3.053384 4.5450927,3.6858043 3.4465333,5.0750881 3.3545389,6.946172 4.3134119,8.3979881 5.3311122,9.9388746 7.214027,10.599356 8.946616,10.023204 9.1505499,9.955389 9.4071244,9.8543064 9.5167821,9.7985767 L 9.7161596,9.6972504 10.023243,10.081848 c 0.227738,0.285225 0.295628,0.398401 0.26275,0.438017 -0.05855,0.07055 -0.09911,0.01559 1.573726,2.132677 2.805495,3.550547 2.88212,3.644068 2.985684,3.644068 0.05289,0 0.231535,-0.06773 0.396996,-0.150504 z" />
    <path style="fill:#000000;" d="M 14.708217,16.395304 C 14.638935,16.367446 14.02574,15.617738 12.614588,13.835581 10.27118,10.876068 10.124308,10.67985 10.121003,10.504223 10.118647,10.379007 9.7019461,9.8868898 9.6204444,9.9130716 9.5819223,9.9254462 9.3758634,10.003142 9.1625355,10.085729 7.9306935,10.562618 6.512264,10.409936 5.4017786,9.6809131 4.5225043,9.1036784 3.8655111,8.1564398 3.61005,7.0976381 3.5000334,6.6416559 3.5109622,5.6746251 3.6311584,5.2298545 3.8463536,4.4335525 4.2532946,3.7326236 4.8042655,3.2092551 5.2894208,2.748405 5.8264913,2.4340267 6.5207431,2.2045017 6.8646619,2.0907996 6.9172375,2.085427 7.6859973,2.085427 c 0.7673246,0 0.8219776,0.00556 1.1652543,0.1184597 1.4748224,0.4850691 2.5016674,1.5550546 2.8655974,2.985991 0.184589,0.7257883 0.165594,1.5860261 -0.04928,2.2316871 -0.10482,0.3149699 -0.411373,0.9434407 -0.583207,1.1956479 l -0.152034,0.2231453 0.207205,0.2489818 c 0.113963,0.1369403 0.279725,0.2844064 0.36836,0.3277026 0.187731,0.091702 0.233511,0.1457517 2.84766,3.3620496 1.413077,1.738569 1.910953,2.379472 1.910953,2.459925 0,0.458621 -1.15744,1.317468 -1.558289,1.156287 z m -3.986194,-6.034981 c 0.112454,-0.07216 0.300034,-0.235775 0.416845,-0.3635844 0.206159,-0.2255708 0.253579,-0.3102979 0.173667,-0.3102979 -0.02129,0 -0.167782,-0.1573093 -0.325529,-0.3495763 -0.157747,-0.1922669 -0.301778,-0.3670682 -0.32007,-0.3884479 -0.01874,-0.021903 -0.121721,0.043386 -0.235912,0.1495653 -0.111459,0.1036402 -0.293226,0.2530724 -0.403925,0.3320716 -0.1106991,0.078999 -0.2011648,0.1547034 -0.2010351,0.1682313 1.271e-4,0.013528 0.1076995,0.1580712 0.2390431,0.3212068 0.131344,0.1631355 0.276129,0.3585805 0.321746,0.4343225 0.04562,0.07574 0.09369,0.137711 0.106824,0.137711 0.01314,0 0.115892,-0.05904 0.228346,-0.131202 z M 8.6182007,9.9415441 C 9.9486931,9.6021441 11.015385,8.5572424 11.395014,7.2214564 11.50965,6.8180907 11.551209,6.0320333 11.48093,5.5963824 11.215851,3.9531648 9.9235105,2.6608242 8.2802927,2.3957447 7.8514418,2.3265636 7.0580436,2.367084 6.6690482,2.4780341 5.8004902,2.7257661 4.9854699,3.3049342 4.488075,4.0278729 3.9911593,4.7501152 3.7356112,5.8017865 3.8487236,6.6590314 c 0.1981738,1.5019004 1.1925024,2.7187648 2.6084602,3.192247 0.2097457,0.070137 0.5052966,0.1465165 0.6567796,0.1697326 0.3916243,0.06002 1.1052115,0.02232 1.5042373,-0.079467 z" />
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="pie" class="pie">
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" viewBox="0 0 20 24" width="20" height="24">
    <path style="fill:#ffffff" d="M 11.514979,6.2022873 A 3.8401398,3.8401398 0 0 1 7.6748391,10.042427 3.8401398,3.8401398 0 0 1 3.8346993,6.2022873 3.8401398,3.8401398 0 0 1 7.6748391,2.3621475 3.8401398,3.8401398 0 0 1 11.514979,6.2022873 Z" />
    <path style="fill:#e65100" d="m 7.6748391,2.3621475 c 2.1208512,-2e-7 3.8401399,1.719289 3.8401399,3.8401398 0,2.1208508 -1.7192887,3.8401397 -3.8401399,3.8401397 z"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="title" class="title">Title</div>
    <div id="menu_button" class="menu-button"> <img id="menu_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/l6GysYf.png">    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="display" class="display">
    <div id="speech_bubble" class="speech-bubble">
    <div id="logo_animation" class="logo-animation" data-flip-id="logo">
    <img id="logo_animation_image" src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/Z1oYdpUd9Txyop1jdH/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611436e68e9fdddc32ce5e4e6c3a4730caba6ef8f0c&rid=giphy.gif&ct=s">
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much. So for the first question, I don't know why it's like that. Creating a pie wedge progress bar is surprisingly complex so I found the simplest code snippet I could find since I don't like using code I don't completely understand.

The second question I don't quite understand. The logo image is a png with a transparency, and my plan was to position the pie svg behind the magnifying glass. If you mean what is the purpose, it's a pie/wedge shaped progress bar I'm animating with GSAP. Sorry I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works, but I know that creating a circular progress bar generally requires animating/setting the styles of both halves and then combining them so it seemed easier to trust that someone else's code would work than trying to understand the nuances behind getting the right effect.

I'm guessing you probably didn't realize that though, in which case will that svg still work for my purpose?

Comment: You said "Forget about the png logo and use mine" but that's not the logo part? My div has a png head-shaped logo div, and a sibling pie div that contains an SVG I'm trying to position behind it. The screenshot you sent is exactly what I need. Though I'm keeping the head white, the orange fill I was planning to change too once I positioned it. But I just don't understand from your instructions what you want me to do with the SVG you created or why that's different than the SVG I have now?

Comment: And does that work with the Javascript animation since there's no data-percentage attribute in your SVG? Sorry I really appreciate the time you put into this, I'm just not really understanding what it is I should do with it? I don't have much experience with using CSS with SVG but I'm more confused now than I was before.

Comment: Also I love the idea of animating the bubble speech and making it a SVG, I'm going to do that so thanks so much for the advice.

Comment: Well, if you had explained all that in your question it would be better for undestanding the issue and the whys. Anyway you can use my svg, just add the proper ids to the two paths in the middle. The fisrt would be the white circle and the second the pie, but as i just sliced it at half to make you see the effect you just copy the white circle and paste it instead of the orange and set the color and the id necessary for GSAP to animate it.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't clarify and thank you again. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I can't figure out how to get the image to fill the available vertical space of the div. Also how is the progress feature supposed to work if the data-percentage is only on one of the paths? I tried setting it to 100 to test and as expected it only fills halfway.

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/RwVJZEe

Comment: The problem is that in the codepen I can't see any animation. So I can't say what's happening. Try to change the transform of the second circle, or even suppress it. I have no experience with GSAP either so I will be of poor help on that. My strengths are in svg itself. Maybe if you send me a complete code including the whole html, css and javascript so that I can run it locally to see if I can get the catch. I don't know if it is allowed sending contact information here.

Comment: I haven't animated it yet, but when I said animated progress bar I just mean if it's set at 0 and you enter 75, it's going to smoothly transition from 0 to 75%. I don't really care about it being animated though, mostly I'm just trying to do what I said in my original post and get that div positioned behind the transparent part of the png. I don't mind using your SVG instead if it looks identical especially since you took the time to make it, but that's not the main thing I'm trying to do. I do appreciate the time you took to try to help me though.

Comment: Revisit my answer please.

Comment: Thanks, could you look at this Codepen and let me know why it's so small and not aligned even though both .pie and .logo are defined together? I'm sorry to keep asking you questions, I really don't know anything about SVG which is why I decided to use someone else's code snippet for my pie/progress bar. I have no idea how to change the CSS styling of this type of element.

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/YzVvYjL

Comment: Now you can up vote the answer. It's responsive and perfectly aligned. You have made a certain mess up in css trying to style those elements defining them together. Let me know if it fits your needs or at least is a new starting point.

Comment: Thank you so much and I'm sorry for all the work you had to do to help me out. I appreciate it.

Comment: But, did my answer helped you or not?

Comment: It did, I'm having a separate and unrelated issue I need to fix before I put it all together, and I've also been learning more about SVG and paths so I can set the CSS properties. I realized if the width and height is defined in the SVG file in pixels, it limits the max size it can be. So I actually did the CSS styling working for the head and magnifying glass before you responded, and I'm just fixing a couple things before I add the pie-wedge progress bar. But everything works, it was just my lack of understanding so thank you.